# Java NoClassDef found error when executing via terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, azure, call-graph

I am trying out a Digital Signature project with Microsoft Azure blob storage. I built the project using Eclipse Neon and it is executing perfectly.

I want to execute java-callgraph for the same project so that I get to know the run time executions/interactions with Azure.

The terminal command that I used is :

> java
>   -Xbootclasspath:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-storage/4.0.0/azure-storage-4.0.0.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.0/jackson-core-2.6.0.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/code/flexiprovider/1.7/flexiprovider-1.7.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/code/CoDec/21/CoDec-21.jar:/home/pallavi/Experiment/Azure/target/Azure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -javaagent:/home/pallavi/git/java-callgraph/target/javacg-0.1-SNAPSHOT-dycg-agent.jar
>   -jar /home/pallavi/Experiment/Azure/target/Azure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I also tried:

> java
>   -Xbootclasspath:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/pallavi/Experiment/Azure/target/Azure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   -javaagent:/home/pallavi/git/java-callgraph/target/javacg-0.1-SNAPSHOT-dycg-agent.jar
>   -classpath /home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-storage/4.0.0/azure-storage-4.0.0.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.0/jackson-core-2.6.0.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/code/flexiprovider/1.7/flexiprovider-1.7.jar:/home/pallavi/.m2/repository/com/code/CoDec/21/CoDec-21.jar
>   -jar /home/pallavi/Experiment/Azure/target/Azure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

And I get NoClassDef error for

> javax/crypto/BadPaddingException

, while the project runs perfectly with eclipse IDE itself.

I tried the solutions to the same issue posted and the error still pertains. This is a maven project and the pom.xml has all dependencies.

Can someone please help me resolving this or suggest a way that java-callgraph can be executed via eclipse IDE to serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, per my experience, I think the referenced library `jce.jar` missed in your command which be include in the path `jre/lib/`.

Meanwhile, I suggest that you can refer to the [eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm) to export a runnable jar file which packaged all referenced libraries to reduce the terminal command length.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.